# Zygote keeps restarting force-stopped app

Tags: chrome-for-android

I've got Chrome running on a Pixel 4a (Android 11).  If I close the app manually (i.e., swiping with my finger), it closes as expected.  However, if I run `am force-stop com.android.chrome` from an `adb` shell, it's restarted a second later by Zygote.  The same thing happens if I send it a `SIGKILL`.

The browser really is being closed as the new process has a different PID.  Examining `/proc/<pid>/status`, I see that the parent PID corresponds to the Zygote process.

Why can't I close the app for good with `am`?

Comment: Sounds to me like Android has some sort of app-recovery/restart in case the process was not properly ended (process crash or kill). Have you checked logcat if it contains any details why and how the app restarts?

Comment: I see: `ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://localhost/... flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main (has extras)} from uid 10215`

Comment: And which app is the UID `10215`? Note that even with swiping, you cannot keep an app stopped forever. See [Why do apps run in background?](https://mirfatif.github.io/IAnswers/why_android_apps_run_in_background). Disclosure: the link belongs to me.

Comment: @IrfanLatif, the UID belongs to com.android.chrome.